# Simple random distribution of N items on n cells

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, distribution

I want to simply distribute N items in n cells, both numbers N and n can be large, so I wouldn't like to loop over random as here:

```
import numpy as np

nitems = 100
ncells = 3
cells = np.zeros((ncells), dtype=np.int)
for _ in range(nitems):
    dest = np.random.randint(ncells)
    cells[dest] += 1
print(cells)
```

In this case, the output is:

```
[31 34 35]
```

(the sum is always N)
Is it there any faster way?

Answer (score 1):

An answer to the question (I have to thank here to @pjs for his help) follows.  I think it is the fastest, and probably, the shortest and most space efficient one possible:

```
from numpy import *
from time import sleep

g_nitems =   10000
g_ncells =   10
g_nsamples = 10000

def genDist(nitems, ncells):
    r = sort(random.randint(0, nitems+1, ncells-1))
    return concatenate((r,[nitems])) - concatenate(([0],r))

# Some stats

test = zeros(g_ncells, dtype=int)
Max = zeros(g_ncells, dtype=int)
for _ in range(g_nsamples):
    tmp = genDist(g_nitems, g_ncells)
    print(tmp.sum(), tmp, end='\r')
    # print(_, end='\r')
    # sleep(0.5)
    test += tmp
    for i in range(g_ncells):
        if tmp[i] > Max[i]:
            Max[i] = tmp[i]

print("\n", Max)
print(test//g_nsamples)
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified that the counts have to have any particular distribution as long as they add up to N, so the following will work as requested:

```
import numpy as np

nitems = 100
ncells = 3
range_array = [np.random.randint(nitems + 1) for _ in range(ncells - 1)] + [0, nitems]
range_array.sort()
cells = [range_array[i + 1] - range_array[i] for i in range(ncells)]
print(cells)
```

It generates an ordered set of random values between 0 and `nitems`, then takes successive differences to generate the desired number of cell counts.

The complexity is O(`ncells`) rather than O(`nitems`), so it should be more efficient when there are substantially more items than cells.

Comment: This is a great solution, as it needs the minimum amount of random numbers generation, and the minimum amount of explicit loops. I've simplify it to even more, here: gist.github.com/3608e423b2cbf218ace3d10f5d8b062c
It avoids explicit Python iterations (slow) using internal C numpy functions (fast)

Comment: I'm totally freaked out with this statistics, why the last cell always receives double the amount the others [here](https://gist.github.com/e8371d4b84dfb62a6fbf9b92be90436d)

Comment: Finally fixed, I don't know how (grrrr!), but fixed (same link of gist as before)

Comment: Thanks pjs for checking out **my** solution ([here](https://gist.github.com/e8371d4b84dfb62a6fbf9b92be90436d)) is 20 times faster than your standard Python list-comprehension.

Comment: Sorry, I'm novice here, as you can deduce from my "reputation", and when I tried to add a comment with code here to your answer, I couldn't.  So I thought, as I have seen it elsewhere here, it could only be possible linking the code outside from here.

Comment: @juanfal Don't try to put code in comments, it really doesn't work well--particularly for Python, which is totally dependent on white space!  You can create your own answer to your question, or you can edit existing answers, although your edits are subject to approval/acceptance.  If you re-read the help section, you'll note that the idea is to make a question and the responses be self-contained here on SO, and to not depend on outside resources.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine, your code with a `timeit` took 151 microseconds. The following took 11 microseconds:

```
import numpy as np
nitems = 100
ncells = 3
values = np.random.randint(0,ncells,nitems)
cells  = np.array_split(values,3)
lengths= [ len(cell) for cell in cells ]
print(lengths,np.sum(lengths))
```

The result of the print is `[34, 33, 33] 100`.

The magic here is using `numpy` to do the splitting, but note that this method will split as close to uniform as possible.

If you want the partitioning done randomly:

```
import numpy as np
nitems = 100
ncells = 3
values = np.random.randint(0,ncells,nitems)
ind_split = [ np.random.randint(0,nitems) ]
ind_split.append(np.random.randint(ind_split[-1],nitems))
cells  = np.array_split(values,ind_split)
lengths= [ len(cell) for cell in cells ]
print(lengths,np.sum(lengths))
```

This takes advantage of `numpy.array_split` taking indices of where to perform the split as an argument (rather than the number of near-uniform partitions).

Comment: I think this solution more for loops than necessary.  It also misses random-behaviour when it looks for a random based on a previous random range. On the other hand it creates many pieces and, in the solutions provides, has even another hidden loop avoided due to the fact that the number of cell is three, what is wrong